# Problem From Hungerford (Abstract Algebra) (Ch 1 Section 1)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

The Question:

> Let $a,b,c,$ and $q$ be as in Exercise 5. Suppose that when $q$ is divided by $c$, the quotient is $k$. Prove that when $a$ is divided by $bc$, the quotient is also $k$.

Exercise 5 Question:

> Let $a$ be any integer and let $b$ and $c$ be positive integers. Suppose that when $a$ is divided by $b$, the quotient is $q$ and the remainder is $r$, such that
>   $$a = bq + r \text{ and } 0 \leq r < b.$$
>   If $ac$ is divided by $bc$, the quotient is $q$ and the remainder is $rc$.

**What I have done so far:**
Let $a=bq+r, 0 \leq r < b$, and $q=ck+z, 0 \leq z < c$, where $a,b,c,q,k,z$ are integers. Then it follows that:
$$a = bq + r \implies a = b(ck+z)+r \implies a = bck + bz + r, 0 \leq bz+r < bc.$$
What I am stuck on is how to show the last inequality is true. I have tried manipulating the inequalities given:
$$ 0 \leq r < b, 0 \leq z < c \implies 0 \leq rc+bz < bc \implies 0 \leq bz + r < bz + rc < 2bc $$
$$ 0 \leq bz + r < 2bc $$
I think this is to no avail. Can anyone give me tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
0\le bz+r \le b(c-1)+(b-1)=bc-1 < bc.
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why $bz + r \leq b (c-1) + (b-1) $? I'm having a hard time seeing that.

Comment: @itspax b is smaller than c, so it is at most c-1. Similarly for r

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti why is b smaller than c ?

Comment: It is a typo it is z

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm super late I'm sorry. but the problem only want you to show k. so set r = to zero and you are done. you don't need z. when you substitute you will get 2r, then set are to zero.

Comment: This wouldn't be enough. You can't assume that the division is exact.